# Jenkins: setting environment variables from a global function

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multi-branch pipeline project with a scripted Jenkinsfile in SCM. I want to set environment variables in my pipelines from a shared global function. My shared global function looks like this:

```groovy
#!/usr/bin/groovy

def call(String envName = 'staging') {

  def json = libraryResource 'env-config.yaml'
  def config = readYaml text: json
  def envObj = config.environments.find{it.name == envName}
  environment {
    PROJECT = ${envObj.project}
    ARTIFACTS_REPOSITORY = ${envObj.artifacts_repository}
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_PREFIX = ${envObj.docker_registry_prefix}
  }
  println "${envObj}"
}
```

But in my Jenkinsfile, I don't see these set:

```groovy
timestamps {
  withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'xxx', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
    node('klm') {
      try {
        def revisionTag
        loadEnvConfig('staging')
        println "project=${env.PROJECT}, repo=${env.ARTIFACTS_REPOSITORY}"
        ...
```

`env.PROJECT` and `env.ARTIFACTS_REPOSITORY` are both null. If I return the `envObj` from the function and print the properties in the pipeline, I can see them. Is it possible to set environment variables from my function?

Edit: I just realized that I am unable to set any environment variables in my Jenkinsfile in a multi-branch pipeline. E.g. both these patterns don't work

```groovy
timestamps {
  withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'xxx', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
    node('klm') {
      try {
        environment {
          FOO = "bar"
        }
        println "project=${env.FOO}"
        ...

timestamps {
  withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'xxx', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
    node('klm') {
      try {
        withEnv(["FOO=BAR"]) {
        println "project=${env.FOO}"
        ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what `environment` is and why it isn't failing the run for you. `PROJECT = ${envObj.project}` is not valid Groovy, so that block is not getting executed. It looks like you are trying to use the [`environment` directive for declarative pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment), but, you are using scripted pipelines. The options below are only valid for scripted pipelines due to limitations of shared libraries and declarative pipelines.

In your current code, you aren't modifying any global script variables or returning values to be used in other steps, so they do not take any effect. You have a couple different approaches depending on the API you want to present to consumers.

The first option is to just modify the `env` global variable:

```groovy
env.PROJECT = envObj.project
env.ARTIFACTS_REPOSITORY = envObj.artifacts_repository
env.DOCKER_REGISTRY_PREFIX = envObj.docker_registry_prefix
```

These will modify the global `env` state that will be available everywhere else in the script (unless they are overwritten or removed).

Another option, is to write the method using the existing [`withEnv` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-withenv-code-set-environment-variables) and allow consumers to supply a `Closure` body. Here is an example where I have renamed the function from `loadEnvConfig` to `withEnvConfig`:

```groovy
def call(String envName = 'staging', Closure body) {
  // Previous code... 
  withEnv([
      "PROJECT=${envObj.project}",
      "ARTIFACTS_REPOSITORY=${envObj.artifacts_repository}",
      "DOCKER_REGISTRY_PREFIX=${envObj.docker_registry_prefix}",
  ]) {
    body()
  }
}
```

`Jenkinsfile`

```groovy
withEnvConfig('staging') {
  println "In block project=${env.PROJECT}, repo=${env.ARTIFACTS_REPOSITORY}"
}
println "Out of block project=${env.PROJECT}, repo=${env.ARTIFACTS_REPOSITORY}"
```

Inside of the body they are set to the values of `withEnv`. Outside of the block, they are reset.

I much prefer this sort of pattern to modifying global state.